# Why does my count becomes 0 when my random number is greater than the number I write?

Tags: c

I have written C code for a game where a random number is generated and the user has to guess the correct number. So, whenever the I write a number and it is greater than the random number, my code is executing as it should. However when I write a number which is less than the random number,the count variable becomes zero, instead of decreasing the count value by 1. I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong?
I have attached the image of my output where the problem can be seen.[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

main()
{
    time_t t;
    int a,count=5;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));
    int randomnumber=rand()%21;
    printf("This is a guessing game, Only 5 tries are left\n");
    printf("enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf(" \n");
    if (a>=20){
        printf("ERROR!! Enter number only between 0-20\n");
    }

    printf("You only have %d tries left\n",count);
    printf("enter number only between 0-20: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf(" \n");
    if (a==randomnumber){
        printf("You guessed it correctly, YOU WIN!!\n");
    }
    else{
        for(count=4;count>=1;count--)
        {
            if (a>randomnumber){
                printf("My number is smaller than that\n");
                printf("You only have %d tries left\n",(count));
                printf("enter number again: ");
                scanf("%d",&a);
                printf(" \n");
            }
        }
        if (a<randomnumber){
            printf("My number is greater than that\n");
            printf("You only have %d tries left\n",(count));
            printf("enter number again: ");
            scanf("%d",&a);
            printf(" \n");
        }
        if (a==randomnumber){
            printf("You guessed it correctly, YOU WIN!!\n");
        }
    }
    if (a!=randomnumber)
    {
        printf("You LOOSE!!, the Number was %d",randomnumber);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (a<randomnumber)` is not in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests for `a < randomnumber` and `a == randomnumber` are not inside the `for` loop. So you only check them after you've counted all the way down to `0`.

You need to put all the tests inside the loop. You should also use `else if` so that you don't check the new number that they've entered on the same iteration (since you haven't decremented `count` yet).

And you need to break out of the loop when they guess the number.

The simplest way to organize this is to take all the code that prompts for the next number out of the `if` blocks, since it's the same for less than and greater than. The `if` blocks just print which way the error was, and break out when they win.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

main()
{
    time_t t;
    int a,count=5;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));
    int randomnumber=rand()%21;
    printf("This is a guessing game, Only 5 tries are left\n");
    printf("enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf(" \n");
    if (a>=20){
        printf("ERROR!! Enter number only between 0-20\n");
    }

    printf("You only have %d tries left\n",count);
    printf("enter number only between 0-20: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf(" \n");
    if (a==randomnumber){
        printf("You guessed it correctly, YOU WIN!!\n");
    }
    else{
        for(count=4;count>=1;count--)
        {
            if (a>randomnumber) {
                printf("My number is smaller than that\n");
            } else if (a<randomnumber) {
                printf("My number is greater than that\n");
            } else {
                printf("You guessed it correctly, YOU WIN!!\n");
                break;
            }
            printf("You only have %d tries left\n",(count));
            printf("enter number again: ");
            scanf("%d",&a);
            printf(" \n");
        }
    }
    if (a!=randomnumber)
    {
        printf("You LOOSE!!, the Number was %d",randomnumber);
    }
    return 0;
}
```